# complex eigenvalue for limit problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We consider the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
y''+\lambda y=0\\
y(0)-2y(2\pi)=0\\
y'(0)-y'(2\pi)=0
\end{cases}
$$
The question is to prove that this problem doesn't admit complex eigenvalues, using the following indication: we put $\lambda=\alpha +i \beta$ and we prove that $\beta=0$. How can we use this indication? Please.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard argument that works. Suppose $y$ is a non-trivial solution of the stated problem. Then $y+\lambda y=0$ and $\overline{y}+\overline{\lambda}\overline{y}=0$, which leads to
$$
    (\lambda-\overline{\lambda})\int_{0}^{2\pi}|y|^2dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(\lambda y)\;\overline{y}-y\;\overline{(\lambda y)}dx \\
     = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(-y'')\overline{y}-y(-\overline{y''})dx \\
     = \int_{0}^{2\pi}y\,\overline{y}''- y''\,\overline{y} dx \\
     = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d}{dx}\{ y\,\overline{y}'-y'\overline{y}\} dx \\
     = \{ y\overline{y}'-y'\overline{y}\}|_{0}^{2\pi}=0.
$$
Therefore, if $\lambda\ne\overline{\lambda}$, then $y=0$ because $\int_{0}^{2\pi}|y|^2dx = 0$.

Comment: Please, what you do exactly to obtain the first relation $$(\lambda-\overline{\lambda})\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} |y|^2 dx =0....$$? and why $$\displaystyle\int_0^{2 \pi} y \overline{y}''-y''\overline{y} dx= \displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{d}{dx}\{y \overline{y}'-y'\overline{y}\}dx$$? Please

Comment: @jiji : $(\lambda-\overline{\lambda})|y|^2= \lambda y\overline{y}-\overline{\lambda}y\overline{y} = (\lambda y)\overline{y}-y\overline{(\lambda y)}$. For the second, $\frac{d}{dx}(y\overline{y}'-y'\overline{y})=y'\overline{y}'+y\overline{y}''-y''\overline{y}-y'\overline{y}'= y\overline{y}''-y''\overline{y}$.

Comment: for the one, i don't understand, sorry. You multiplye the equation $y''+\lambda y=0$ by $\overline{y}$?

Comment: @jiji : The first is just the distributive law of multiplication, followed by the associative law, with $\overline{ab}=\overline{a}\overline{b}$.

Comment: It should be $y''+\lambda y =0$ and so on.